# Json schema definition for repeated objects

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I'm trying to define a schema and the sample object in my mind looks like below. Does this look like a valid structure? Properties inside `branded` and `unbranded` are copies. I'm pretty new to this. Is there any recommended approach and other suggestions, documentation? I was not able to google this information and was hoping I'll get guidance here.

```
{
"a": true,
"b": false,
"branded": {
    "c": true,
    "d": false,
    "e": false
},
"unbranded": {
    "c": false,
    "d": true,
    "e": false
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what are you trying to achieve with schema over here?

Comment: Above is an example, purposefully didn't provide schema for simplicity. Schema would help define additions to existing spec (could be request/response)

Comment: Same info for "c", "d", "e" except inverted. Why not only renaming "c" to "c_branded" ?

Comment: Ah, thats an interesting take. Thanks @damorin